# Countdown timer Java JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

Can someone please help me make a countdown timer in JavaFX? I need the time to be taken from a label (the time is set by a slider) and I want to see the minutes and seconds remaining every second. The countdown should start when a button is pressed. I searched Stack Overflow and I tried to do it with ChatGPT, but I still have problems with it.

```java
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;

public class MainController implements Initializable{

@FXML
private Button button;

@FXML
private Slider slider;

@FXML
private Label timerLabel;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

//the initial value of the label is set with the slider

slider.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> num, Number oldVal, Number newVal) -> {
            Integer value = Integer.valueOf(String.format("%.0f", newVal));
            timeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(value));

        });

}

//the action of the button

@FXML
private void start(){

//i tried another way and still does not work
timer = seconds;
Timer timerA = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
           if(timer >0){
                timeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(timer));
                timer--;
           }
           if(timer == -1){
                 timeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(timer));
                 timerA.cancel();
           }
        }
};
timerA.schedule(task,0,1000);
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe we can solve the problems if you [edit] your question and include the code ChatGPT produced…

Comment: @deHaar i just edited the post. The problem with the code produced by chatgpt is "Timeline might not be initialized" and even though i tried to initialized i keep having problems

Comment: The code generated by ChatGPT is garbage (no surprise there). The timeline's event handler is not guaranteed to execute exactly every second; it will just execute *when a frame is being rendered*, if a second or more has passed. So this timer will tend to run slow. When the start button is pressed, find the current time (`LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.now()`), compute the time when the timer should finish (`LocalTime endTime = startTime.plusHours(...).plusMinutes(...).plusSeconds(...);`). Then start an `AnimationTimer` that updates the label.

Answer (score 4):

The immediate issue ("timeline might not be initialized") is answered by [@VGR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77446372/2189127). However, using a `Timeline` like this is simply not the way to create a countdown timer. The issue is that the timeline does not guarantee to call the event handler every second; it will merely be executed when the UI is rendered, if *at least* a second has passed.

When the countdown is started, you should compute the time at which it should end. Then "periodically" update the label by calculating the time remaining until the end time. You can do this part either with a timeline, or with an `AnimationTimer` (whose `handle()` method will be called each time the UI is due to be rendered). The `AnimationTimer` will add a little extra computation time at the expense of being as accurate as the JavaFX system will allow; here I think the computation is minimal enough that it is not an issue and would prefer that approach.

Here is the `startComputation()` method using this approach:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class CountdownTimer extends Application {
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    private int seconds;

    private Label timerLabel = new Label();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        TextField hoursField = new TextField();
        hoursField.setPromptText("Hours");
        TextField minutesField = new TextField();
        minutesField.setPromptText("Minutes");
        TextField secondsField = new TextField();
        secondsField.setPromptText("Seconds");

        Button startButton = new Button("Start Timer");
        startButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            // Parse user input for hours, minutes, and seconds
            hours = Integer.parseInt(hoursField.getText());
            minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutesField.getText());
            seconds = Integer.parseInt(secondsField.getText());

            // Start the countdown timer
            startCountdown();
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(hoursField, minutesField, secondsField,   startButton, timerLabel);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Countdown Timer");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void startCountdown() {
        LocalTime end = LocalTime.now()
                .plusHours(hours)
                .plusMinutes(minutes)
                .plusSeconds(seconds);
        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long l) {
                Duration remaining = Duration.between(LocalTime.now(), end);
                if (remaining.isPositive()) {
                    timerLabel.setText(format(remaining));
                } else {
                    timerLabel.setText(format(Duration.ZERO));
                    stop();
                }
            }

            private String format(Duration remaining) {
                return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                        remaining.toHoursPart(),
                        remaining.toMinutesPart(),
                        remaining.toSecondsPart()
                );
            }
        };

        timer.start();
    }
}
```

If you prefer a `Timeline`, replace the `startCountdown()` method with

```
    private void startCountdown() {
        LocalTime end = LocalTime.now()
                .plusHours(hours)
                .plusMinutes(minutes)
                .plusSeconds(seconds);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> {
            java.time.Duration remaining = java.time.Duration.between(LocalTime.now(), end);
            if (remaining.isPositive()) {
                timerLabel.setText(format(remaining));
            } else {
                timerLabel.setText(format(java.time.Duration.ZERO));
                timeline.stop();
            }
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }

    private String format(java.time.Duration remaining) {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                remaining.toHoursPart(),
                remaining.toMinutesPart(),
                remaining.toSecondsPart()
        );
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the effort but i still have a problem, remaining.isPositive() does not work. Do i keep having problems because this is a JavaFX project?

Comment: @MsLaus The first code block contains a complete, executable example (which is also a JavaFX project, identical to yours) that compiles and runs. What do you actually mean by “does not work”? Make sure you are using an up-to-date JDK (`Duration.isPositive()` was introduced in version 18; current version is 21)

Comment: Thank you! Finally, the code works how I want to. I appreciate the effort! I needed to use JDK21 (i used 17 because until now i did not have any problem) and give up the method i wrote for the button.

Answer (score 2):

The message “timeline might not be initialized” means that you are trying to use `timeline` before it has been constructed.  You are calling `timeline.stop()` inside an event handler which is being passed to the Timeline constructor;  since the constructor hasn’t completed yet, the compiler cannot guarantee `timeline` has actually had a value assigned to it when your event handler runs.  In other words, `timeline` might be initialized.

One way to address this is to add the KeyFrame separately.  That way, the Timeline constructor has completely finished:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
// Construction complete;  now timeline can be used in an event handler.

timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), event -> {
    // Decrease one second
    if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
    } else {
        // If seconds reach zero, decrement minutes and set seconds to 59
        if (minutes > 0) {
            minutes--;
            seconds = 59;
        } else {
            // If minutes reach zero, decrement hours and set minutes and seconds to 59
            if (hours > 0) {
                hours--;
                minutes = 59;
                seconds = 59;
            } else {
                // If hours, minutes, and seconds reach zero, stop the timer
                hours = 0;
                minutes = 0;
                seconds = 0;
                timeline.stop();
            }
        }
    }
    // Update the label with the new values
    timerLabel.setText(String.format("Time Left: %02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
}));
```

Another way would be to declare `timeline` as a private field, rather than as a local variable.  This works because, once the enclosing class has finished its own constructor, every field is guaranteed to be initialized.  (If your code never assigned a value to a field, that field would automatically be initialized to null.)

Comment: This timer won't work properly though. There is no guarantee as to when that event handler is invoked: you can't assume that decreasing the countdown by one second is correct.

Comment: @James_D What do you mean?  You mean it’s not a perfect real-time clock?  I think that much is understood.

Comment: @VGR firstly, I want tot thank you for the effort but it still does not work properly, the label's text remains the same

Comment: I'm not sure the extent to which it is understood. This timer could slow down if the UI is busy rendering other parts of the UI. That should not happen, even if the timing isn't perfect. Even under ideal circumstances, the event handler is only invoked 60 times per second, so you could easily see 1-2% inaccuracies under ideal circumstances.

Comment: @James_D I agree that using java.time is important for accuracy, but I got the impression that this is an exercise rather than an end user application.

Comment: @MsLaus The code is working for me.  Is it possible that you’re creating more than one Label, or something?  It might help to edit your question and turn the code into a short but complete standalone program (what we call a [mre]).

Comment: Even if this is only an exercise, I disagree that this is an appropriate solution. It just serves to encourage misunderstanding of how JavaFX animations work. We don't know what the exercise is aiming to teach, but people will always learn things that are not directly part of the exercise anyway.

Comment: And to clarify: *"I agree that using java.time is important for accuracy"* it's not using `java.time` specifically. The point is to save the end point of the timer and recompute the remaining time each time, rather than to recompute the remaining time from the current remaining time. Surely that's critical to understand for implementing any kind of timer, no matter the context? (I.e. don't repeatedly accumulate errors in computations.)

Comment: @James_D Yeah, I was thinking as I wrote that there’s obviously other ways to accurately track the time besides using java.time, but I didn’t want to get too far off-topic.  It is critical, but I think it might be a more advanced topic than this particular task aims to teach.

Comment: @VGR I just edited the text to a minimal reproducible example.  What I am trying to reach is a program for my portofolio that should help people focus on a task for a period of time setted by the user, something similar to Forest App if you know this App.

Comment: @MsLaus I appreciate the attempt, but you want to keep your original code in your question.  Without it, all of the existing comments and answers don’t make sense.  If you want to add another program, that’s fine too.  That said, stay away from Timer and TimerTask.  JavaFX, like most GUI frameworks, requires that its methods are called in one specific thread.  Calling them in any other thread, as Timer does, will cause unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @VGR thank you for the effort ! The code works now how I wanted to!